# reinitialize jquery plugin on ajax event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqtransform

I'm trying to use [this plugin](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/) (jqtransform) to make some nicer looking checkboxes. However the checkboxes that I'm trying to apply it to are put on the page through an ajax `get()` request, where the html is pulled from a remote file.

```
//apply custom styles to checkboxes
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    console.log('ajax complete');
    //find all form with class jqtransform and apply the plugin
    $("form").jqTransform();
});
```

doesn't initialize these new checkboxes. Is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to call your plugin in "success" function for the $.get(), something like

```
$.get(myurl, {
    success: function() { 
        $("form").jqTransform();
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, this will work. I was just looking for something that would take care of it for all get requests, without having individually to place this initialization in each one..

Comment: Does you console.log called? Do you have a page to check with that code?